# Ember.js options for updating a view

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I've been playing around with `Ember.js`, and was wondering what are the best practices for updating the `DOM` on a data change.

Specifically, I have dividers with open and close buttons in them for each instance of a model. I want the open button to disappear if the state of the model object is "open", and the close button to disappear if the state of the model is "closed".

As far as I can tell, there are a couple of options.

A) Directly change elements in the DOM with `jQuery` in the view that called by the controller

B) Setup an observer that will auto reload the template, and have `if/else` statements in the template where things should change based on the model parameters that got updated.

Is one of those preferred (or neither)? What would you guys do?

Comment: I don't think you have to do any of that if you're using Ember.js with handlebar templates, as the values in your model that are bound to your template will be automatically updated. Perhaps you want to re-phrase your question?

Comment: just updated the post a bit to better explain what I was going for.

Comment: Wrote a little fiddle for you, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/7Uk7J/) which shows this implemented in the **other** view/tab. This sample is using a simple `Em.Controller` instead of a `Em.CollectionController`, but it does what you need.

I have 2 css classes:

```
.visible {visibility: visible}
.invisible {visibility: hidden}
```

The following view is using them on `classNameBinding` at the child view. And I'm binding the model to the parent view with `contentBinding` pointing to the model at the controller, then the child view has a property that observes the `currentState` property at the parent.
When you click this child view, it will set the `currentState` to 'closed' and it will evaluate the `IsVisible` method again, which feeds the proper value to the classNameBinding.

```
App.OtherView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'other',
    contentBinding: 'controller.content',
    currentStateBinding: 'controller.content.state',
    ButtonView: Ember.View.extend({
        tagName: 'a',
        click: function(e) {
            this.set('parentView.currentState', 'closed');
        },
        classNameBindings: 'IsVisible:btn visible:invisible',
        IsVisible: function() {
            return this.get('parentView.currentState') === 'open';
        }.property('parentView.currentState')    
    })        
});
```

Here's how the template is being set up

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="other" >
    <h2>Other</h2>
    ID: {{content.id}}<br />
    Name: {{content.name}}<br />
    State: {{content.state}}<br />
    {{#view view.ButtonView }}
        Close
    {{/view}}            
</script>
```

---

Alternatively, I have this [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/hEx84/show) (here's the [source](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/hEx84/)) that's very similar in the concept of how to use the `.property` to achieve this same functionality, but this is a little more complex and that's for a navbar menu. Check how I'm doing the `App.NavigationView`, you'll find a child view named `NavigationItemView` which I have a `classNameBinding`. What this does is check the value of a property in my controller and then on the view. That comparison returns true or false, and it will populate the class name based on the expression that calls the `isActive` function property, almost same as the first fiddle that I wrote based on your question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, thats great man, thanks for the answer! Ember is awesome, its a little tough getting into it from square one though! Seriously appreciate the answer though.

Comment: Glad it helped :) You should mark this as the answer, that could help other people with a similar problem to identify this question/answer

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to detail your question. This is my answer based on the current understanding of your question:
From my point of view both options are not a good practice with EmberJS. As far as i learned until now, it is one of the strengths of EmberJS, that you do not have to worry about manually updating the DOM. All you need to do is updating your Model or Controller Objects and all changes will automatically be propagated to the DOM automagically.

Best regards,