# Updating partial style content

Tags: ember.js

I would like to do the following handlebar script:

The color:{{object.labelColor}} seems not working (Cf. other post).

One solution seems to bind the complete style attribute on the "javascript side" but I would like to avoid managing the "fixed" part of the style (text-align:left) on that side.

Is there a solution to make something similar to my sample code (dynamic part on the js side,fixed part on the html view) ?

```
<div class="label" style="color:{{object.labelColor}};text-align:left">{{object.name}}</div>
```

Comment: that's not how you should update the `style` property because its value is a string, so you'd have update the entire string. Alternatives to that would be creating a css class with the style you want and have `classNameBindings` observe a function that would in the end evaluate the class name. Another option would be using `$.css` from within a `propertyDidChange` handler, observing the property that would trigger the color change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **have** to use styles instead of classes, and want to change only a portion of the style strings at the time, one alternative would be using [`$.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), applying the style changes you want. [**For example**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/jTS6w/):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h1>App</h1>
  {{view App.SomeView}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="some-view">
  <div style="color:#00F;text-align:left">
    Some View<br />
    <button {{action changeColor on="click"}}>Change Color</button>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

App = Em.Application.create();

App.SomeView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'some-view',
  changeColor: function(e) {
    console.log('changing color');
    this.$('div').css('color', '#F00');
  }
});

</script>
```

In the script above I'm using jQuery's `css` function to change the `color` attribute whatever elements my selector returns from within `SomeView` instance (in this case as I only have one div, I'm using the element as a selector). There are other (and likely better) ways to do this, but I hope this helps.

The problem with this solution as it is, is that you can't keep the state of the `style` attribute as it's not bound to any property, that's why I think binding classes would be better in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

You could use  'classNameBindings', and define a set of css rules to the corresponding classes.

## Js

```
Ember.View.create({
 classNameBindings: ['isUrgent'] // array of class names
 isUrgent: true //conditional to set class name
});
```

## css

```
.is-urgent{
 background-color: #356aa0;
}
```

## Resource

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html#property_classNameBindings

Comment: Keep in mind that when using `classNameBindings` with the conditional preperty with the same name as the expected class name, if the provided name is `pascalCase`, it will be transformed to `dashed-lower-case`, so `isUrgent` would come up as `is-urgent` in the rendered template. More info in [**The Guides**](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/)

Comment: Nice! Also, can you use the : to return a value for the classname if the conditional is true - ['isTrue' : 'isUrgent'] ?

Comment: kinda.. check this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345789/ember-js-options-for-updating-a-view/13352374#13352374) in which I talk more about it. But it's sort of like `classNameBindings` interprets its value like "if the conditional property gives me true, I dasherize the conditional and set it as a class or I get the string/segment after the 1st colon (:), if it gives me false, I set nothing, or the segment/string after the last colon"